# Is it possible to develop Indoor navigation by using ARCore?

Tags: android, arcore

I tried to achieve using google's cloud Anchors, but it has a limitation of 24hrs (after that the cloud anchors become invalid).
And another way is creating the replica of Unity, but that would be too lengthy process.

Any other ways please suggest me or any idea: https://www.insidernavigation.com/#solution - how they achieved it?

And how to save the common coordinate system in cloud or locally?

Comment: There is a 2D navigation system using ARCore i have not tested it but you can give it a try https://community.arm.com/graphics/b/blog/posts/indoor-real-time-navigation-with-slam-on-your-mobile?CommentId=7473b37b-8005-4cb6-a1a3-86eecdba5b35

Answer (score 2):

Current versions of ARCore and ARKit have limited persistence capabilities.  So a workaround - which I think is what they use in that site you linked, is to use images/QR codes which they use to localise the device with a real world position and then use the device's SLAM capabilities to determine the device's movement and pose.

So for example, you can have a QR code or image that represents position 1,1 facing north in the real world.  Conveniently, you can use ARCore/ARKit's to detect that image.  When that specific image is tracked by the device, you can then confidently determine that the device is position 1, 1 (or close to it).  You then use that information to plot a dot on a map at 1,1.

As you move, you can track the deltas in the AR camera's pose (position and rotation) to determine if you moved forward, turned etc.  You can then use these deltas to update the position of that dot on your map.

There is intrinsic drift in this, as SLAM isn't perfect.  But the AR frameworks should have some way to compensate against this using feature detection, or the user can re-localize by looking for another QR/image target.

Comment: We recently presented a talk on basically this approach at DevFest 2018 in Melbourne - https://speakerdeck.com/ryanhodgman/wayfinder-indoor-navigation-with-arcore

Comment: @AlgoRyan Have you guys published the source of it, blog post or SDK?

Answer (score 0):

As far as my knowledge is concern, This Virtual Positioning system has not been introduced yet in Google arcore. The link you provided, these guys are using iBeacon for positioning.

Comment: I don't think they used iBeacons and it's completely developed using AR

Comment: There is another product like this, Their developer has written that they have done this using iBeacon. You cannot do VPS without having an additional sensor. Google's Tango project was based on VPS and the device should need to have A depth sensor in order to track the positioning.

Comment: it is not true that Project Tango ever needed a depth sensor to track its position. it is just false. the only thing Project Tango ever used for position tracking was the camera and IMU. which is available on every smartphone. Also VPS was never released, it is in the making and not necessarily required except if you need persistence.

Answer (score 0):

yup I believe it could be possible. Currently most developed ways have its limitation .I am working on to find another way with the fusion of Cloud Anchors with IBeacon.